# HLS video stream working with direct s3 link but not through cloudfront

Tags: amazon-s3, video-streaming, amazon-cloudfront, http-live-streaming

I am trying to set up HLS streaming of video files using S3 and Cloudfront. The issue I am having is that the HLS video works when I use the direct S3 link for the manifest file but does not work when I use the Cloudfront link for the file. In the later case, I get a CORS error. The CORS policy on my Bucket is set to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>86400</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <ExposeHeader>Authorization</ExposeHeader>
        <ExposeHeader>Content-Type</ExposeHeader>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

I also have the following crossdomain.xml in my root directory and the root folder where all the hls videos are stored.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
        <allow-access-from domain="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

I have gone through dozens of tutorials, they all say I simply need to set up a web distribution for my bucket and the bucket policy and CORS policy set for the bucket should work.

I have the following permissions on my bucket.
[image: Bucket permissions]

Is there something I'm missing out in my Cloudfront setup ? I left all the values as default apart from the origin(which I set to my bucket).

S3 Link: http://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/tjb-video-data/vod-data/1472453572-11/hls/master.m3u8

CloudFront link: http://d1932r1vgq7q7.cloudfront.net/vod-data/1472453572-11/hls/master.m3u8

(I have tried with http and https)

Comment: `http://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/tjb-video-data/crossdomain.xml` >> `403 Forbidden`.  Also, your CloudFront seems incorrectly configured for CORS.  You need to whitelist the [`Origin:`,`Access-Control-Request-Headers:`, and `Access-Control-Request-Method:` request headers to S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/header-caching.html#header-caching-web-cors) in your CloudFront Cache Behavior config.  Not posting as an answer yet, because this may not be the complete solution, but the header whitelisting is essential for CORS.

Comment: Also, turn off `List` for `Everyone` on your bucket.  You definitely don't want everyone to be able to download lists of all your files, and that's what you have enabled, there.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Perfect ! That did it ! Thank you so much. I needed to whitelist the headers. Strangely enough not even Amazons own tutorial on how to enable CORS does not mention this. It does however say "Forward a whitelist of headers that you specify. CloudFront caches your objects based on the values in all of the specified headers. CloudFront also forwards the headers that it forwards by default, but it caches your objects based only on the headers that you specify." Does this mean my hls video will not benefit from using Cloudfront as all request are sent to origin ?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Ihad enabled List just to see if it would help with the HLS playback. Have disabled it now. Thanks !

Comment: CloudFront caches objects, essentially, against the request sent to the origin server, so if you request a certain path from `Origin: http://example.com` and `Origin: https://example.com`, CloudFront will not use the cached response from one to satisfy the other, because a whitelisted header's value is different.  This is necessary for correct behavior, because varying a header may vary the server's response, but semantically equivalent requests are still served from the cache.  Forwarding *all* headers to a custom origin defeats caching entirely, but that is not what you are doing, here.

Comment: Give me a little time, and I'll write this up as a proper answer.

Comment: did you solve the issue

Comment: Hi, Did you find the solution for this? Please write the answer if you did. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue and resolved it by making the following configuration changes:

1. Open the **Edit behavior** settings for your HLS video origin.
2. Under **Cache key and Origin requests** -> select **Cache policy and origin request policy (recommended)**
3. Under **Cache Policy** -> Select **Elemental-MediaPackage**

[Config Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGAOv.png)